# Choose integers so that average is close to given real number

Tags: integers

I have a list of integers (that are consecutive). I also have a given real value that is between the min and max of the integers. I want to choose any number of integers from the given list, so that the mean of these integers is optimally close to the given real value. (alternatively, choose any number of integers so that the mean is within $\epsilon $ of the given value).

I don't know if this is a well posed problem or if it's even possible to solve/approximate. Any ideas and suggestions of how to approach this problem and even naive solutions are welcome.

Comment: 1- Should it be the minimum of integers? 2- Is an algorithmic solution interesting? Or you need a one-shot solution?

Comment: It's certainly a well-posed problem, that has an obvious solution: try all possible combinations and pick the best. But this solution is computationally infeasible if your list of integers is too long (say more than 30 or 40 elements). So the interesting question is, does there exist an _efficient_ algorithm to find the optimal subset? Let me think about that for a while...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an efficient way: find which fraction of the form $k/l$ (for integer values, and $l <= n$) is closet to your target. All the averages you can get will be of this format. Then observe that for a given $l$, you can get all the consecutive values of $k/l$ in a range.

Example: By picking from $\{1,2,3,4\}$ you can reach:

$l=1: 1,2,3,4$

$l=2: 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5$

$l=3: 2, 2.33, 2.66, 3 $

The range you can reach for $k/l$ is from the average of the first $l$ integers to the average of the last $l$ ones.

Enumerating the range is in the order of $n$ operations, finding the closest one is constant time, so you get an efficient algorithm for reasonable $n$ (millions or less).

I've implemented a rough prototype (C++, someone can probably translate it to Mathematica). See 
http://pastebin.com/91kXULTQ

Example output:

```
target is 3.14159
Average of 
-100, -99, -98, -97, -96, -95, -94, -93, -92, -91, -90, -89, -88, -87, -86, -85, -84, -83, -82, -81, -80, -79, -78, -77, -76, -75, -74, -73, -72, -71, -70, -69, -68, -67, -66, -65, -64, -63, -62, -61, -60, -59, -58, -57, -56, -55, -54, -53, -52, -51, -50, -29, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 
 is 3.14159
```

Quite interesting question.

P.S.: The prototype has precision issues but the algorithm is there.

Comment: Cool algorithm. But this algorithm seems heavily biased towards choosing consecutive numbers no? This seems to be leading to larger errors.

Comment: It gives you the best you can get. Once you identify that the closest fraction is of the form, say, x/17, you just need to pick 17 integers and get the numerator(sum) correct. The range of sum you can get is from the sum of the 17 least to the sum of the 17 largest.

So, yeah, I prefered getting two sequences, and adjusting the position of one value in between but one could just as well keep one consecutive sequence and add a single non-consecutive value. IT would give the same average.